# What is the Azure equivalent of Amazon VM tags?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

Is it possible to store name value pairs on Azure virtual machines? In Amazon EC2 I can use the tags to organize VM's.

I found this article about tags : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-preview-portal-using-tags/ but these seem to be on Resources, not VMs.

What I need is :

```
VM1
    tag1: xx
    tag2: yy
VM2
    tag1: xx
    tag2: y2
```

Then search the vms having tag1 equals xx, then do some jobs on found list. And, these tags could be changed easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. currently Azure does not support tag grouping on VM.

The only way is to make a resource group, not so flexible, but currently they (azure dev team) are actively working on it to move whatever resources across resource groups.

see related: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/6178622-ability-to-move-resources-from-one-resource-group